# Unable to start activity from onReceive method of broadCastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am working on an alarm application.
In this, I am using a broadcast receiver and alarm manager. When the alarm goes off the onReceive method is called and then from the onReceive method, I am calling startActivity to start an intent

BUT the problem that I am facing is that in some devices activity is not getting started when the app is in the background or killed.

In onReceive method, I have three things:

1. Toast
2. RingtoneManager
3. Intent

```
  @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "In broadcast receiver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra(Constants.BROADCAST_RECEIVER_BUNDLE);
        Alarms alarms = (Alarms) args.getSerializable(Constants.ALARM_OBJECT);
        int alarmRequestCode = args.getInt(Constants.ALARM_REQUEST_CODE);


        Intent OpenAppIntent = new Intent();

//      I also tried with adding classes in intent object directly eg new Intent(context, MyActivity.class) but no luck

        OpenAppIntent.setClass(context,com.example.MyActivity.class);
        OpenAppIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        OpenAppIntent.putExtra(Constants.BROADCAST_RECEIVER_BUNDLE , args);
        context.startActivity(OpenAppIntent);

        Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if (alarmUri == null) {
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        ringtone.play();

    }
```

Now we have two cases

1. When we have all three items in onReceive method ( toast, ringtone manager and intent ) - Then toast and ringtone is getting played and displayed respectively and activity is not getting started
2. When we remove the ringtone manager from onReceive method ( toast and intent ) - Then Toast is also not getting displayed ( activity is not started as well )

Devices in which this problem is noticed are Gionee F9, Motorola g5s, and Redmi k20 pro. Also, sometimes the same thing happens with Nokia 7 Plus

Please tell me what's wrong with the code or what is the best way to start an activity when the broadcast is received.

**Test 1**

Instead of starting activity I tried displaying a fullscreen notification as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive) and as suggested in a comment but unable to do so because of Error *Non-static method startForeground(int, notification) cannot be referenced from a static context*

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(Constants.ALARM_OBJECT , alarms);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.BROADCAST_RECEIVER_BUNDLE , bundle);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(Constants.APP_NAME)
                .setContentText("Stop the alarm")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_inner)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
                .build();

        Service.startForeground(1, notification); // Non-static method startForeground(int, notification) cannot be referenced from a static context 
    }
```

**Test 2**

I Also tried starting foreground service directly from the onReceive method but the same problem is occurring as with the starting activity. I also tried debugging by placing breakpoints on the onCreate method of service but onCreate never get called these devices ( Gionee F9, Motorola g5s, and Redmi k20 pro )

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent alarmServiceIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmSoundService.class);
        Bundle alarmServiceBundle = new Bundle();
        alarmServiceBundle.putSerializable(Constants.ALARM_OBJECT , alarms );
        alarmServiceIntent.putExtra(Constants.ALARM_BUNDLE , alarmServiceBundle);
//        startService(alarmServiceIntent);
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, alarmServiceIntent);
    }
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: That's not how you should be handling an alarm, you should be using a [time-sensitive notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive).

Comment: Did you register your receiver in manifest?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks for the suggestion I am giving it a try lets see if this works

Comment: @RavenYang yes I have registered it in manifest

Comment: @ianhanniballake I tried as you suggested but didn't work. please do have a look on the edited question

Comment: @VardanKaushik - the foreground part doesn't apply to your case, just use `notify`